# Video generation from SolidWorks .STL file

Tags: matlab, video, solidworks, volume-rendering

I have received an .stl file and I want to generate a video from it.

It is a SolidWorks originated object and it is a cube.

I want to make a video that displays this cube is doing translation, rotation.

My specific question is how to make a video without images, directly from .stl file with MATLAB.

Comment: I don't know what an stl file is. Please provide some link to this format. In any case, stl means C++ Standard Library hear so I re-tagged your question.

Comment: Start with [this STL file reader](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29906-binary-stl-file-reader) and formulate a more specific question about the rendering once you get the object loaded into a MATLAB structure that can be described here. See also [this MATLAB code](http://www.esmonde-white.com/home/diversions/matlab-program-for-loading-stl-files).